# model django new tables

Tags: django

I just created all the DB tables from one model with 6 classes.

In one of them I would like to add a NEW field.

I did that and hit: `python manage.py syncdb`.

But Django won't add that column in that table.

Am I missing something?

How can i add columns/tables AFTER I already created the db in Django.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a migration tool such as South.

Answer (score 0):

[Chapter 10 of the Django book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter10/) has a section called 'Making Changes to a Database Schema' with a sub-section titled 'Adding Fields'...

Comment: Thanks that was the "django-way" answer I was looking at yesterday.